# Can not reopen ILNumerics plot after it was closed

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

My programs creates several instances of a window with a ILNumerics plot. In most cases, I am able to close the windows and open new ones. However, if I close all the windows and try to open a new one, the program hangs. Any suggestions why?

```
private void PlotWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ILScene scene = new ILScene 
    {
        new ILPlotCube
        {
            new ILLinePlot(ILMath.tosingle(ILMath.randn(1, 10)))
        }
    };
    this.ilPanel.Scene = scene;
}
```

Comment: Might be related to this bug: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis/view.php?id=182 ? Is there any error message / exception?

Comment: Seems similar. But no error message or exception, the application just freeze. Been able to work around it for now by keeping a hidden window in the background, but would prefer a better solution.

Comment: Any idea when the mentioned bugfix will be released to Nuget?